# How to perform boolean operations in BASH (outside conditions)

Tags: bash

There are 20 questions/answers about how to perform boolean operations in conditions:

```
if [ 4 -gt 3 ] && [ 3 -gt 2 ]; then echo "True"; else echo "False"; fi
```

But how to perform boolean operations standalone?

I am looking for something equivalent to following code:

```
bool a=true, b=false, c=true;
bool r1 = a && b;
bool r2 = a && (b || c);
```

In bash, it should be something like:

```
a=1;b=0;c=1
r1=`expr a && b`
r2=`expr a && ( b || c )`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$(( ))` construction

in `man bash` see 'ARITHMETIC EVALUATION'

> The  shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under certain
> circumstances (see the let and declare builtin commands,  the  ((  compound command, and Arithmetic Expansion).

```
r1=$((a && b))
r2=$((a && ( b || c )))
echo $1
0
echo $2
1
```

note

- that `&` is bitwise, while `&&` is logical
- `0` and `≠0` revert to traditionnal/mathematical **0/false** and **≠0/true** value (unlike unix return code)

  ```
   b=$(( 7 & 5 ))
   echo $b
   5
   l=$(( 7 && 5 ))
   echo $l
   1
  ```